# Ajax request call two ormore times on slow internet in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am facing unexpected problems in calling ajax request to submit data on slow internet. Whenever the internet is slow and I submit form data the browser pop-up appears to kill page or wait. If I click on the wait button to complete the process the form data submitted 2 times or more. Anyone here to guide? I am using jquery and asp.net technology and calling web methods in ajax.
Sample code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../WebServices/AddVoucher.asmx/AddJournalInfo',
    async: false,
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    data: '{journalMain:' + JSON.stringify(JournalMain) + ', journalEntry1:' + JSON.stringify(journalEntriesTable) + ', journalAttachmet:' + JSON.stringify(journalAttachmets) + '}',
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean it's slow. Are you saying it's popping up a dialog box saying "A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly"?

Answer (score 0):

Kill Page Pop-up appears when you block the browser thread for a longer period.

I see You're using `$.ajax` with `async: false`.

This is not real ajax it is doing it synchronously as you have said `async: false`

Ajax requests are meant to be async in nature. So AS You're doing `async: false` and internet connection is slow; It is halting browser for a longer duration.

Thus, I will say remove `async: false` from your code or change it to `async: true`

I believe it should solve your issue.

Cheers!